# How to make a new line inside div.span for paragraph

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just learning css so please bear with it, for this may be a simple question:

I have an HTML like this:

```
<div class="span2">
    <p>Some long text</p>
</div>
```

What i want is, when the width of the text exceed the width of the div, it'll go to a new line like this:

```
Some
Long
Text
```

But even when the text width exceed the div's width, it won't go to a new line. Please help and thank you. Note that I'm using twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.span2 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

or

```
.span2 {
  word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Either way, I think you are looking for the word-wrap property.